# How to fix empty container after booking form?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a car booking form on the home page of my Wordpress website. Everything was fine, but few days ago in Google Chrome and FF I start to see empty container between slider and first container with content. In Safari there is no this empty container. website URL: https://www.minskairporttransfer.com

[Here is a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0J8Z.png)

I tried to change CSS but no result. Booking form on PHP in functions.php file and inserted to the homepage with a shortcode.

[Image of admin panel where shortcode inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXWL.png)

This container is empty

```html
<div id="book">
  <div class="fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box nonhundred-percent-fullwidth non-hundred-percent-height-scrolling fusion-equal-height-columns" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);background-position: left top;background-repeat: no-repeat;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;border-top-width:0px;border-bottom-width:0px;border-color:#e5e4e4;border-top-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;">
    <div class="fusion-builder-row fusion-row ">
      <div id="booking_form_pahle_page_par" class="fusion-layout-column fusion_builder_column fusion_builder_column_1_1 fusion-builder-column-1 fusion-one-full fusion-column-first fusion-column-last fusion-column-no-min-height 1_1" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div class="fusion-column-wrapper" style="padding: 0px; background-position: left top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; min-height: 0px; height: auto;" data-bg-url="" data-empty-column="true">
          <div class="fusion-text"></div>
          <div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no content in your container. Is there supposed to be something in it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem,

You are putting the wrong property on an element and its container must have relative position.

This is correct code

```
<style>
   div#car_page{
    position: absolute;
    top: -350px;
    height: auto !important;
   }
   .post-content{
       position: relative;
    }
<style>
```